# Is there a way to parse each unique value of a column into individal CSV's?

Tags: python, pandas

EDIT: Creating files working, removing columns is not

### EDIT2: ALL WORKING! Need help with combining two columns into one key. Is it possible to take two columns, state and county, and then combine them into a state-county key?

I have a COVID-19 data set that I am trying to create tables with. Currently, I have one large dump file from the government github page.

Basically, I am attempting to take every unique value of row State, and create a new csv with the respective columns, only for that state.

So if Arizona has 4 data entries, it would create a new CSV with those four entries.

The sample data set I am retrieving from can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv).

As we can see, the columns contain identifiers, state names, dates, etc.

I am looking to take each individual state, and create a new csv with all the values for that state including state, country, and the dates from 3/23-3/29.

This is a sample of what the data would look like after it is parsed:

[image: Sample Data] 
**What I believe needs to happen**
What I have been working on is parsing out the unique values for the state column, which i did simply through

```
data=pd.read_csv('deaths.csv')
print (data['Province_State'].unique())
```

Now, I am trying to figure out how to select specific column, and write the values for the unique states (including all counties for that same state)

Any help  would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here's what I've tried:

```
def createCSV():
data=pd.read_csv('deaths.csv', delimiter = ',')
data.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])


data = data.set_index('Province_State')
data = data.rename(columns=pd.to_datetime)
for name, g in data.groupby(level='Province_State'):
    g[pd.date_range('3/23/2020', '3/29/20')] \
        .to_csv('{0}.csv'.format(name))
```

However with this, I get unknown string format for the columns that don't have dates. However, I attempted to drop them  based off index, which didn't seem to do anything.

Manually deleting the columns allows for the function i am looking for, but i need to delete the columns with panda for time.

Comment: Hi, i pressed enter early. Please wait while I edit.

Comment: Hi Sammy, you can combine two columns into one key like this: `df.groupby(['state', 'county'])`.  If you want some help with Pandas functions, you might find [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saving by state:

```
for name, g in data.groupby('Province_State'):
    g.to_csv('{0}.csv'.format(name))
```

For saving by state while only using certain dates:

```
data = data.set_index('Province_State')
data = data.rename(columns=pd.to_datetime)
for name, g in data.groupby(level='Province_State'):
    g[pd.date_range('3/23/2020', '3/29/20')] \
        .to_csv('{0}.csv'.format(name))
```

This assumes that the only columns are the region name and the dates.  If this isn't the case, remove the non-date columns prior to converting them to datetimes.

Comment: Hi @ASGM , thank you for this reply! This will help lead me on the right track. There are some columns that don't include date. I will research how to remove these with pandas.

Comment: see my edit. I think I am doing something wrong syntax wise.

Comment: Wow! Your solution works amazing. Thank you so much. If you can offer any help on why it may not be deleting, let me know @ASGM